# visual studio error after restarting my pc: Unable to start program (.exe), system cannot find specified path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im currently working on an assignment for university in C++ and visual studio,

I finished writing code and compiled, there were errors with the code but still compiled, i restarted my pc loaded up visual studio and then when I went to compile I got the error "cannot start program, system cannot find specified path for the .exe file and i havent changed anything in my code since it compiled earlier.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the compiled executable still there? Can you run it sepatately from VS?

Comment: There isnt any .exe file in the project folder or debug folder for some reason, it was there before the reboot, I dont have any third party AV running on windows.

Comment: ***there were errors with the code but still compiled*** I believe it did not compile  but it let you run the previous version. VS prompts you when the build failed if you want to run the previous executable anyways.

Comment: So because there were errors it caused the .exe to be deleted when I tried to compile it ?

Comment: update: issue was due to having 2 main bodies in 2 seperate cpp files, thanks for helping :)